# Hide markers on embed google map on clicking in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As shown in the picture bellow [image: picture]
Whenever i select any serial number i want to only show the marker which is for the selected serial number.

By default i am viewing this [image]

Also, the search functionality is in separate partial view which is called in the chart view and the map is called in layout for chart bellow is the code for both

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MultiGraph", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{


    <div class="form-inline">
        @Html.DropDownList("search", null, "Select Serial Number", new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:20%" })

        <input type='text' name="start_date" id="startTime" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date" autocomplete="off" />
        <input type='text' name="End_date" id="endTime" class="form-control" placeholder="End Date" autocomplete="off" />
        <input id="recall" type="submit" value="Show Chart" class="btn btn-success" autocomplete="off"/>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")">
            <img src="~/Image/back-button.png" alt="Go Back" title="Go Back" >

        </a>
        @*<input type="button" value="Back" class="btn btn-success" onclick="@Html.ActionLink("Index","Home")"/>*@
        @*<button class="btn btn-success form-control" onclick="" name="Back" value="Back"></button>*@
    </div>}
```

Now passing this partial view into Chart view

```
 <div style="font-family:'Times New Roman' ; font-size:large" align="center">

    @Html.Partial("_Search")

</div>
```

Bellow is the code for embed google map

```
<td style="text-align:center; width:22%; font-size:large; background-color:#C8E6C9; color:black">


                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1-VlXsvMWMr8EotfMcIwYKt-1SrI" width="320" height="350" style="margin-top:-383px"></iframe> </td>
```

How to do it i have no idea 
Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What are you doing?

You are showing a static image with the URL

https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1-VlXsvMWMr8EotfMcIwYKt-1SrI

in the code

```
<td style="text-align:center; width:22%; font-size:large; background-color:#C8E6C9; color:black">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1-VlXsvMWMr8EotfMcIwYKt-1SrI" width="320" height="350" style="margin-top:-383px"></iframe> 
</td>
```

### Google My Maps

This static image was generated by [Google My Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/) which is a tool with a graphic interface that allows users to create personalized maps to check later. This tool is not meant to generate dynamic URLs for applications like you are trying to do because every URL must be manually generated.

For more information about Google My Maps you can check the following URL
https://support.google.com/mymaps/?hl=en#topic=3188329

### Google Static Maps API

The solution to your problem lies somewhere else. If you want to go with a static image to display, you can use [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/).

This API allows you to generate dynamic URLs that then return static images. 
An example of this working would be

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Williamsburg,Brooklyn,NY&zoom=13&size=400x400&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C11211%7C11206%7C11222&key=AIzaSyAa9-cVfW-usm6ebJTQBGYEsE2MrDWCIHU

In this example I specify the center to be "Williamsburg,Brooklyn,NY" and I create an image with zoom of 13, and a size of 400x400 pixels.
Additionally, this image also has three markers in color blue.

**Do remember to create your own API_KEY and to use it in your own project.** This parameter will allow you to control the number of requests made, and other information.

In this example I am using my StackOverflow API Key `key=AIzaSyAa9-cVfW-usm6ebJTQBGYEsE2MrDWCIHU`, but you should create your own.

Static Maps is a big web service and you can read more about it in the following link
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Markers

### Solution

A solution to your problem would involve the following steps:

1. Check which Serial number the user selected
2. Create an URL in your application matching the location of that serial number (remember to create an image with the right width and height values of width="320" height="350")
3. Put the created URL in `<iframe src="CREATED_URL_HERE" style="margin-top:-383px"></iframe>`
4. And voilá !Everything works !

---

There it goes, hope it helps!

Comment: i want that the selected serial number marker is shown only in the map and other markers will hide